# C# Cast list using Linq using Where function

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to optimize part of a function that gets objects within Unity that contains a certain component.

Current code looks like this

```
Collider[] collisions = Physics.OverlapSphere(point, range);
foreach (Collider item in collisions)
{
      if (item.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>())
      {
           rigidbodies.Add(item.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>());
      }
}
```

First I get a list of objects with colliders, then I run thought a foreach loop to get the ones that also contains a Rigidbody2D component

I'm trying to turn this into a single line of code using LINQ. I'm trying to do something along this line

```
Collider[] collisions = Physics.OverlapSphere(point, range);
rigidbodies = (List<Rigidbody2D>)collisions.ToList().OfType<Rigidbody2D>().Where(x => x.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() == true);
```

Unfortunately this just throws an InvalidCastException

Comment: And the error is of course correct, the object you have isn't a list, and you're trying to pretend that it is in fact a list.  You need to *actually create a list* rather than telling the compiler that a non-list object is really a list.

Comment: I don't think you are doing the right optimization here, there is no guarrantee that linq will be any faster, but setting `item.GetComponent<>()` to a variable will reduce the need to retrieve the value twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a call to `ToList()` on to your method chain.

You'll also be able to get rid of the cast altogether:

```
rigidBodies = 
    collisions
        .OfType<RigidBody2D>()
        .Where(x => x.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>())
        .ToList();
```